# change QCursor on scrollbar in QgraphicsView

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview

I have changed the cursor on a `QGraphicsView` using:

```
graphicsView->setCursor(QCursor(Qt::CrossCursor));
```

but I don't want the cursor to change on scrollbars of this graphicsView.

Any idea on how to do?

Comment: Brain dump: `graphicsView->viewport()->setCursor()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
graphicsView->verticalScrollBar()->setCursor(QCursor(Qt::ArrowCursor));
graphicsView->horizontalScrollBar()->setCursor(QCursor(Qt::ArrowCursor));
```

Comment: sorry for delay to replay (it's timezone thing).